# Finding common terms in an expression to simplify further?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Writing a big expression into one line is always hard. I usually simplify the expression further by manually finding some common terms (numerator and denominator) and give it some name. However, this becomes very tiring for very large expressions.

To illustrate what I mean, consider the following examples.

**Example-1:**

Consider the following expression, 
$$\frac{(a+b)^2}{1+a+b}$$
It can be seen that $a+b$ can be replaced with some variable, say c, which simplifies the expression to,
$$\frac{c^2}{1+c}$$ 
where, $c = a+b$.

**Example-2:**

Consider the following expression, 
$$\frac{x (a+b)+y (c+d+e)^2+z (f+g)^3}{(a+b)^2+c+d+1}$$
It can be seen that $a+b$ can be replaced with some variable, say $m_0$, $c+d$ with $m_1$, and $f+g$ with $m_2$. By using those variables the expression simplifies to,
$$\frac{x m_0 + y (m_1+e)^2+z m_2^3}{m_0^2+m_1+1}$$ 
where, $m_0 = a+b$, $m_1 = c+d$., $m_2 = e+f$.

---

```
expr1 = (a+b)^2/(1+a+b)
expr2 = ((a + b) x + (c + d + e)^2 y + (f + g)^3 z)/(1 + (a + b)^2 + c + d)
```

---

**Question**

How do I obtain common terms such as $c$, $m_0$, $m_1$, and $m_2$ automatically without any manual intervention? Is this even possible at all?

I don't have any idea of how to approach this. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `FirstCase[Compile[Evaluate[Variables[expr2]], Evaluate[expr2]], _Function, 0, All]` suggests `a + b` for the 2nd expression.

Comment: ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression`` could work.

Comment: @Roman Thank you for the link. I guess this can be considered a duplicate.